# RahpaelJS image resize

Tags: javascript, raphael

I want to resize an image in RaphaelJS following this example: ... . You can see there that you can move the mouse as fast as you want, and the resize is pretty smooth.

In my example: ... , even if I use the same technique, the resize is not that smooth and sometimes it stops. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the Resizing option in your second link?

Comment: Both work pretty smooth for me. Have you tried in a different browser/on a different machine for comparison?

Comment: Resizing an image is a vastly more complex operation than resizing a solid color rectangle

Comment: K.A.G: right bottom corner, you will see the resize cursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't need to set cursor type to 'move' or 'se-resize' on mousemove. Try to put that on mousedown event only. You always changing the type of your movement

So if you press mouse button to resize, it is still posible to change cursor type to 'move' when you move your mouse fast.